# How to stop command line process in Java

Tags: java, command-line, cmd

I have a program that allows a user to press a button, and then it runs a command line statement that the user is able to see the output of.

I now want to know if it's possible to stop the command before it finishes.
I know of the command "ctrl+c" when running command prompt normally, however, I'm not sure how you would implement this in a java program.

```
runButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r) {
        JFrame runFrame = new JFrame("Running process...");
        runFrame.setSize(500, 400);
        runFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        runFrame.setLayout(null);
        JButton somethingButton = new JButton("Stop");
        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        somethingButton.setBounds(65, 290, 105, 25);
        closeButton.setBounds(335, 290, 105, 25);
        JTextArea run = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane runSP = new JScrollPane(run);
        runSP.setBounds(65, 50, 375, 200);
        run.setLineWrap(true);
        run.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        run.setEditable(false);
        runFrame.add(runSP);
        runFrame.add(somethingButton);
        runFrame.add(closeButton);
        runFrame.setVisible(true);
        //Start of creating of command line stuff
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = runtime.exec("ping riot.de");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.err.print("Error: " + e1);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            run.setText(sb.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }

        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent c) {
                runFrame.dispose();
            }
        });

        somethingButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent c) {
                //CODE TO STOP HERE
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: System.exit(0); doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Stultuske I don't want to close the entire program. This is a small snippet.

Comment: so ... you want to 'stop' the application, without 'stopping' the application? you mean interrupt a thread?

Comment: @Stultuske So I'm running a command line statement within Java. I want to stop the command line statement without ending the Java application

Comment: You mean like [`Process::destroyForcibly`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) ?

Comment: the only 'command line statement' you actually run is java MyApplication ... to stop that, you need to end the Java application. All other command line inputs are nothing but that: input.

Comment: I'll look into this, thank you @JornVernee

Comment: @Stultuske OP is talking about this: `process = runtime.exec("ping riot.de");`

Comment: Yes, thank you @MarkoTopolnik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try  using the mentioned code to destry the process `process.destroy();`

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look

Comment: I'm getting this error: Local variable process defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Comment: I believe the issue is bcz of the runFrame object which is declared locally in runButton.addActionListener() but is referred in the inner class for closeButton.addActionListener() and compiler wants that to be declared as final

Comment: Sorry, I'm still quite unaware of the stack traces.

Is this it? 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Local variable process defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

 at MainFrame$4$2.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:177)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: that's correct @Plumel, I already posted the cause of issue in my previous comment.

Comment: Cheers mate, I'll take a look

Comment: Got it sorted. Simply changed the Process 'process' to public at the top of my program.

Comment: Thats Grt8 @Plumel